# Loop function across multiple XML files in directory so each XML becomes a row in a CSV

Tags: python

I've figured out how to get data from a single XML file into a row on a CSV. I'd like to iterate this across a number of files in a directory so that the data from each XML file is extracted to a new row on the CSV. I've done some searching and I get the gist of having to create a loop (perhaps using the OS module) but the specifics are lost on me.

This script does the extraction for a single XML file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

tree = ET.parse("[PATH/FILE.xml]")
root = tree.getroot()

test_file = open('PATH','w',newline='')

csvwriter = csv.writer(test_file)
header = []

count = 0
for trial in root.iter('[XML_ROOT]'):
item_info = []
if count == 0:
    item_ID = trial.find('itemid').tag
    header.append(item_ID)
    data_1 = trial.find('data1').tag
    header.append(data_1)
    csvwriter.writerow(header)
    count = count + 1

item_ID = trial.find('itemid').text
item_info.append(item_ID)
data_1 = trial.find('data1').text
trial_info.append(data_1)
csvwriter.writerow(item_info)
test_file.close()
```

Now I need to figure out what to do to it to iterate.

Edit:
Here is an example of an XML file i'm using. Just for testing i'm pulling out `actrnumber` as `item_id` and `stage` as `data_1`. Eventually I'll need to figure out the most sensible way to create arrays for the nested data. For instance in the `outcomes` node, nesting the data, probably in an array for `primaryOutcome` and all `secondaryOutcome` instances.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='anzctrTransform.xsl'?>
<ANZCTR_Trial requestNumber="1">
  <stage>Registered</stage>
  <submitdate>6/07/2005</submitdate>
  <approvaldate>7/07/2005</approvaldate>
  <actrnumber>ACTRN12605000001695</actrnumber>
  <trial_identification>
    <studytitle>A phase II trial of gemcitabine in a fixed dose rate infusion combined with cisplatin in patients with operable biliary tract carcinomas</studytitle>
    <scientifictitle>A phase II trial of gemcitabine in a fixed dose rate infusion combined with cisplatin in patients with operable biliary tract carcinomas with the primary objective tumour response</scientifictitle>
    <utrn />
    <trialacronym>ABC trial</trialacronym>
    <secondaryid>National Clinical Trials Registry: NCTR570</secondaryid>
  </trial_identification>
  <conditions>
    <healthcondition>Adenocarcinoma of the gallbladder or intra/extrahepatic bile ducts</healthcondition>
    <conditioncode>
      <conditioncode1>Cancer</conditioncode1>
      <conditioncode2>Biliary tree (gall bladder and bile duct)</conditioncode2>
    </conditioncode>
  </conditions>
  <interventions>
    <interventions>Gemcitabine delivered as fixed dose-rate infusion with cisplatin</interventions>
    <comparator>Single arm trial</comparator>
    <control>Uncontrolled</control>
    <interventioncode>Treatment: drugs</interventioncode>
  </interventions>
  <outcomes>
    <primaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Objective tumour response.</outcome>
      <timepoint>Measured every 6 weeks during study treatment, and post treatment.</timepoint>
    </primaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Tolerability and safety of treatment</outcome>
      <timepoint>Prior to each cycle of treatment, and at end of treatment</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
      <outcome>Duration of response</outcome>
      <timepoint>Prior to starting every second treatment cycle, then 6 monthly for 12 months, then as clinically indicated</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>
    <secondaryOutcome>
  <outcome>Time to treatment failure</outcome>
  <timepoint>Assessed at end of treatment</timepoint>
    </secondaryOutcome>

...   

</ANZCTR_Trial>
```

Comment: I just need to run the script across all XML files in the directory. They all should have the same basic XML structure. There's no criteria for which files other than being in that directory. Once I figure out how the iteration works, I'll build out the XML extraction more but I want to get it working on a simple extraction across multiple files first.

Comment: Can you post example of XML?

Comment: Added truncated version of XML in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply generalize your process in a method and iterate across files with `os.listdir` assuming all XML files reside in same folder. And be sure to use context manager using `with` to better manage the open/close file process.

Also, your header parsing is redundant since you name the very tags that you extract: *itemid* and *data1*. Node names likely stay the same so can be hard-coded while text values differ, requiring parsing. Below uses list comprehension for a more streamlined collection of data within XML files and across XML files. This also separates the XML parsing and CSV writing.

```
# GENERALIZED METHOD
def proc_xml(xml_path):
   full_path = os.path.join('/path/to/xml/folder', xml_path)
   print(full_path)

   tree = ET.parse(full_path)
   root = tree.getroot()

   item_info = [[trial.find('itemid').text, trial.find('data1').text] \
                   for trial in root.iter('[XML_ROOT]')][0]

   return item_info

# NESTED LIST OF XML DATA PER FILE
xml_data_lst = [proc_xml(f) for f in os.listdir('/path/to/xml/folder') \
                      if f.endswith('.xml')]

# WRITE TO CSV FILE
with open('/path/to/final.csv', 'w', newline='') as test_file:
   csvwriter = csv.writer(test_file)

   # HEADERS
   csvwriter.writerow(['itemid', 'data1'])

   # DATA ROWS
   for i in xml_data_lst:
      csvwriter.writerow(i)
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you. So I got this running on a test directory with 5 files in it, however the CSV it generates just runs on the first file 5 times, rather than moving on to each file. Once I get that up and running, i'll need to figure out how to deal with nested nodes (some repeating) in the XML as I expand it from just getting it running to my actual use case.

Comment: *just runs on the first file 5 times* ... are you sure? Maybe you copied the test XML five times in directory. Otherwise, check `for f in os.listdir('/path/to/xml/folder')` loops through all five files.

Comment: yes so when I run `os.listdir` on the path to the directory it loops through all 5 files. I think the issue might be with `def proc_xml(xml_path):
   tree = ET.parse(xml_path)`. Where it says `xml_path` do I want to path to a single XML, the XML directory or just `xml_path`. When I put the path to a single XML file in the `tree` part it runs as I said. When I put `xml_path` I get an error. In addition, I'm sure all 5 files in the directory are different.

Comment: Possibly it may be due to where this script is placed as xml parsing assumed relative not absolute paths. See edit to concatenate folder to file name and now prints full path name.

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Now i'll be moving on to try and figure out how to incorporate sub-nodes and repeating nodes into all this.

Answer (score 0):

While `.find` gets you the next match, `.findall` should return a list of all of them.  So you could do something like this:

```
extracted_IDs = []
item_IDs = trial.findall('itemid')
for id_tags in item_IDs:
    extracted_IDs.append(id_tag.text)
```

Or, to do the same thing in one line:

```
extracted_IDs = [item.text for item in trial.findall('itemid')]
```

Likewise, try:

```
extracted_data = [item.text for item in trial.findall('data1')]
```

If you have an equal number of both, and if the row you want to write each time is in the form of `[<itemid>,<data1>]` paired sets, then you can just make a combined set like this:

```
combined_pairs = [(extracted_IDs[i], extracted_data[i]) for i in range(len(extracted_IDs))]
```

Comment: So the issue here is that each XML file has the same contents but only 1 of each element in each file. So I need to find a way to have the script repeat on each file, writing the data I want into a new row in the CSV. I don't think this solution does that. The files I'm pulling may grow and expand, I just kept it to 2 in the script as an example.